# How to correct voltage overshoot in clock divider output?

Tags: digital-logic, clock, latch, cadence, frequency-divider

I am trying to make a quadrature phase divide-by-6 clock divider circuit in cadence. I managed to complete the circuit and obtained the correct waveform; however, due to some reason I am getting a overshoot of voltage in one of the waveform (see below, 3rd waveform). This is 150mV above 1V.

[image]

Can you please suggest methods to correct this?

The circuit design is below:
(inv: inverter,
 by2: divide-by-2 clk divider,
 by3: divide-by-3 clk divider,
 ff_prot: D flip-flop)

[image]

Comment: Match impedances.

Comment: Do you seriously expect us to debug a circuit you haven't shown us?

Comment: @DaveTweed Sorry for not providing the circuit. I've added it to the question. I managed to correct some part of it by replacing the latch with a flip-flop (ff_prot, in circuit); but there is still approx 80mV of overshoot.
I'm using C2MOS circuit for D-latch design.

Comment: How will you analyze reflections without geometry of conductors and dielectric? and /or impedance?

Comment: I just need some insight into what all possible reasons could be for this behavior.
I'm not sure I understand which impedance you are indicating to, here. For all the parameters I know, the transistor length and width used are ->
PMOS: L=80nm W=4um;
NMOS: L=80nm W=2um;
Wire width=0.0625um).

Comment: There is a wave reflected which , Adds a certain percentage of the original wave implying that the load is slightly higher than the transmission line impedance

Comment: Or there is Certain amount of load loss or crosstalk in the layout between something and Q2. Change the clock and look at results say from 5 to 5.5 GHz

Comment: I don't think this is a reflection from a mismatched line. The time is 150ps, which means that the trace must be about 1 inch long. Which is very unlikely in silicon chip. If this was simulated with real placement and power-ground layers, I would suspect some ground bouncing or other interference from something else.

Comment: Looks pretty good for 5 GHz square waves and  you haven’t learned about crosstalk or transmission line effects yet ?

Comment: We did not consider the transmission line or cross talk effects but I suspect that could be something we can look into. It also appears that there may be some clock misalignment in the last flip flop (due to inverter delays coming from by3). We're trying to introduce some transmission gates that might help. Through the C2MOS design is faster but the draw back ultimately is requirement of CLK and CLKN. The requirement is to run it at 1GHz but we're trying to push it to 5GHz. Thank you for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to circuit. Suspecting clock delay due to inverters as an issue, first I added two inverters in series on Q2, but it did not help. Moreover it looked very redundant due to 3 inverters in series. So, we took Q4 and inverted it again to get Q2. Surprisingly enough, it fixed the issue. I suspect the problem was during to the switching action of flip flop.

It works fine now. Thank you for help. :)

This is circuit:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If ringing is the culprit, absent rigorous electromagnetic analysis, a simple approach would be to insert series resistances at each gate output and link their value to a variable. Run a few trials varying the resistance from 15 to 150 Ohms. The minimum ringing will likely occur inside that range. If you need to fine tune, the outputs with a higher fan-out will need a lower R value or maybe zero. This is called source termination. The gate output inductance plus the intermediate conductors can interact with the gate input capacitance to cause reflections after the transitions.
[How to select source termination resistors by looking at signal?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/163332/how-to-select-source-termination-resistors-by-looking-at-signal)
Alternately, The waveform in Q2 may have some cross coupling by way of the power supply or ground. A probe on one or both could reveal a need for a lower impedance power supply or grounding net.

Comment: That's a good sugestion but I am not working on the discrete electronics but rather on IC design so introducing resistances would not be a good idea.